# Wick rotation for calculation of the heat kernel for massive scalar field in curved spacetime

Tags: partition-function, qft-in-curved-spacetime, wick-rotation

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. I am interested in the calculation of $\det(\square_g+m^2)$, more precisely in the evaluation of the partition function:
\begin{equation*}
Z[g]=\int \mathcal{D} \phi\,e^{i \int d^4x\,\mathcal{L}[\phi]}.
\end{equation*}
Where $\mathcal{L}[\phi]=-\frac{1}{2}\phi(\square_g+m^2)\phi$. I know  that:
\begin{equation*}
\ln \det(\square_g+m^2)=\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int d^4x \lim_{y \rightarrow x} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}dt\,t^{s-1}\sqrt{-g}\langle x | e^{-t(\square_g+m^2)} | y \rangle,
\end{equation*}
but from here I am stuck, I've read [Heat Kernel Espansion: User's Manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138) by D.V. Vassilevich where is given the expansion of the heat kernel for manifold, but I found nothing for manifold with lorentzian signature. I think I have to do a Wick rotation but how should I proceed for general manifold?

Answer (score 0):

You have not read about Lorentzian "heat kernels" probably because the continuation of heat kernels to "wave  kernels" would not be very useful. The heat kernel is useful precisely because $G(x,x',t)$  gets  small rapidly when $x$ and $x'$ are far apart. So it explores the geometry only in  the neighbourhood of $x\sim x'$ and  this feature gives it a calculable  asymptotic expansion in terms of the local geometry (curvature tensor etc).  In Lorentz signature, the wave kernel would be large when $x$ is near $x'$  in the Lorentz pseudo-metric, and in this measure  $x$ and $x'$ do not have to be neigbours in the manifold topology. Consequently  there is unlikely to be a useful  expansion of either the kernel or the functional determinant in terms of local geometry.